# Callback function after jQuery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint-2013

I have a function which makes a jQuery ajax call to a REST endpoint.  This function will be run 5-6 times with different endpoints to collect data to validate against.  During this time I would like to display a spinner on the browser screen to indicate to the end user that the program is processing.  I'd like to then hide the spinner once complete.  I'm struggling to figure out how to get this to work.  My thought would be a simple callback function. I've tried putting the callback function in the click method and the css method as well as directly in the ajax call (validateAcctStr) and none of these seem to work.  I feel like there is something simple I am missing?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(disableSpinner){
    $("#json-overlay").css("display", "block");
    validateAcctStr("ValidationAccount", "#accountTxt", "#acctValid");
    validateAcctStr("ValidationBusiness", "#businessTxt", "#busValid");
});
    function disableSpinner(){
        $("#json-overlay").css("display", "none");
        alert("test");
    }
});
```

This is what I have so far for my ajax call (it pulls data from a SharePoint list):

```
function validateAcctStr(list, inputField, validationField) 
{
$.ajax({
    url: "https://urlAddress/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+list+"')/items?$orderby=Title asc&$top=4999",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
success: function(data){
    $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){
            var arrayVar = $(inputField).val();
            if(item.Title === arrayVar){
                $(validationField).html("Valid").css({"background-color": "green", "color": "white", "text-align": "center"});                  
                return false;
            } else {
                 $(validationField).html("Invalid").css({"background-color": "red", "color": "white", "text-align": "center"});
            }
        });
    }   
});
}
```

Comment: Doesnt work means what?

Comment: you defined `disableSpinner` within your document ready handler, but then did nothing with it.

Comment: you called the parameter of the click handler function *disableSpinner*, but this should be the event, and doesn't matter how do you call it. And of course, you never call the function to disable your spinner.

Comment: @Mihai the spinner keeps spinning and the alert doesn't trigger.  No sign that it executes.

Comment: @MarioSantini  I guess that's where i'm confused.  I'm new to callback functions and not sure where exactly I would place it.  I have added it in various places with different results, none of which show the spinner, run the queries, then hide the spinner.

Comment: @nate I suppose inside the click handler you should activate the spinner, and then you should disable on the *success* handler of the *$.ajax* call. Add an error handler too, in which you disable the spinner, otherwise your spinner will remain active if you got an error from the server.

Comment: @MarioSantini if I disable the spinner in the success handler I believe it  will stop and start multiple times (since the function is going to be run multiple times).   I was hoping to have it spin until all the functions completed.  I thought this might be possible as a callback to the click event so that it would run after all the functions in the click event completed, but maybe this is the wrong approach.

Comment: @Nate have a look at my answer update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost all pieces in place, just have to put the thing in the proper order.

The issue is that you never call the *disableSpinner* function.

As you have several other small things, I'll show you changing your code.

So your *$(document).ready()* staff will became:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(ev){
        activeSpinner();
        validateAcctStr("ValidationAccount", "#accountTxt", "#acctValid");
        validateAcctStr("ValidationBusiness", "#businessTxt", "#busValid");
    });
});
```

When you have the other javascript code:

```
// You worked well wrapping the code to disable the spinner in a function
// let's do it for the activation too.
function activeSpinner() {
    $("#json-overlay").css("display", "block");
}

function disableSpinner() {
    $("#json-overlay").css("display", "none");
    // this is just for test:
    // alert("test");
}
```

And the ajax call:

```
function validateAcctStr(list, inputField, validationField) {
$.ajax({
    url: "https://urlAddress/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('"+list+"')/items?$orderby=Title asc&$top=4999",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
success: function(data){
    disableSpinner(); // As the first task you have to disable the spinner.
    $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){
            var arrayVar = $(inputField).val();
            if(item.Title === arrayVar){
                $(validationField).html("Valid").css({"background-color": "green", "color": "white", "text-align": "center"});                  
                return false;
            } else {
                 $(validationField).html("Invalid").css({"background-color": "red", "color": "white", "text-align": "center"});
            }
        });
    },
 error: function(err) {
    disableSpinner(); // to avoid spinner active on an error
    // do something with the error.
 }
});
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you need to wait untill a list of callbacks are complete, than you should use  a slighty complicated approach.

You could introduce promises, but you have to rewrite almost all your code.
in your case you should use callbacks:

```
function callbackCounter () {
    var count = 0;
    return {
        set: function (n) {
           count = n;
        },
        incr: function () {
           cont++;
        },
        done: function() {
            count--;
        },
        doneAll: function() {
            count = 0;
        },
        isDone: function() {
            return count === 0;
        }
    }
}

// ...
$("#submit").click(function(ev){
    activeSpinner();
    var countCallbacks = callbackCounter ();
    countCallbacks.set(2);
    validateAcctStr("ValidationAccount", "#accountTxt", "#acctValid", countCallbacks);
    validateAcctStr("ValidationBusiness", "#businessTxt", "#busValid", countCallbacks);
});

function validateAcctStr(list, inputField, validationField, countCallbacks) {

// snipp...
success: function(data){
    // here you decrement the callbacks:
    countCallbacks.done();
    if (countCallbacks.isDone()) disableSpinner(); // As the first task you have to disable the spinner.
},
```

The same code in the error handler.

Comment: Hey Mario, thanks a bunch for the help!  This seems to work if the function is only being run once.  The problem I'm having is that I'm going to be running this function multiple times (probably 6 times) and I'd like the spinner to remain active until all the functions complete.  Maybe I just need to wrap all those functions in one function.  I think this gets me down the path I need to go though.  I'll play around with it and update when I have it working.  Thanks!

Comment: @Nate you don't need to do that, just use the *callbackCounter()* properly, including all the callbacks you need to wait for. For example you could create the object in your global scope and use set or incr to count the callbacks when you launch.